# robots.txt file dissallow option

Tags: robots.txt

I want to prevent the robots from accessing URLs that end with `/new`. I am modifying my `robots.txt` file as follows:

```
Disallow: /*/new
```

Is this the correct pattern to use to disallow access to all urls terminating in `/new`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes seems google supports this

Try https://www.google.com/webmasters "Site Configuration > Crawler access" to test your robots.txt file for given URLs

Here is the result of this tool

```
http://www.***.com/new/asdasd
Allowed by line 6: Allow: /

http://www.***.com/asdasd/new/
Blocked by line 8: Disallow: /*/new
Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions

http://www.***.com/asdasd/new   
Blocked by line 8: Disallow: /*/new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Disallow: /new$
```

will check for URLs terminating in `/new`